# To consume a web service with multiple input arguments in mule

Tags: web-services, mule, mule-studio

I'm a beginner, I have a mule flow, in which i would like to call SOAP web service operation which has 4 input arguments
"public double calculateInterest(double principal, double year, double rate, int appid)".

I tried using a file or http endpoint where i end up in String array, or object array while using set payload.
the exception thrown is

cannot be cast to java.lang.Double. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: String[]

Could somebody suggest the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can configure file or http inbound, write a java component (remove cxf component), extract parameters from payload, cast in the required type and call web-service method from the component.

Answer (score 0):

see here is an example of a simple webservice :-

```
<mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd ">
    <flow name="getCalculationFlow1" doc:name="getCalculationFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="getCalculation" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.services.getcalculation.v1.GetCalculation" doc:name="SOAP"/>
        <component class="com.services.schema.getcalculation.v1.GetCalculationImpl" doc:name="Java"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

where **com.services.getcalculation.v1.GetCalculation** is the webservice class which is generated using **Apache CXF** from **WSDL** files and  **com.services.schema.getcalculation.v1.GetCalculationImpl** is the implemantation class of webservice ... hope this help

Comment: This webservice has 4 inputs

Comment: I believe he is looking for an example with cxf:jaxws-client, i.e. a Web Service consumer.